# Is it possible to apply NSAttributedString to CPTTextLayer's Text

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I want to display a "custom label" for each index of `CPTScatterPlot`. `CPTTextLayer` takes the textcolor, font size, etc from `textStyle` property. I want to display each character of the string which is displayed in the `CPTTextLayer` with a different color. I know it is possible using `NSAttributedString` but when I passed this argument to `[[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:attributedStr]`, my application crashed. Is it possible to apply a `NSAttributedString` to `CPTTextLayer's` text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Plot currently does not support attributed text. You can add an enhancement request to the [Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list) so that this feature is considered for inclusion in a future version.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 1.3 CorePlot does allow creating CPTTextLayer based upon NSAttributedString. Here's example:

```
NSString *smallTextPart = @"Small part ";
NSString *bigTextPart = @"and the bigger one";

NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", smallTextPart, bigTextPart]];

[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, smallTextPart.length)];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0] range:NSMakeRange(smallTextPart.length, bigTextPart.length)];

CPTTextLayer *txtLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithAttributedText:str];
```

It also works properly with multi line CPTTextLayer labels (you can split CPTTextLayer into separate lines using '\n' character).

Cheers.